# Python MySQL Insert Python 'series' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql

I have a data frame that is an aggregation in which I am attempting to insert into a MySQL database.  The data looks like the following:

```
                first                last  count      type  \
group                                                            
1     2018-01-12 00:00:00 2018-01-13 23:00:00    189  Received   
2     2018-01-13 23:15:00 2018-01-14 00:00:00      4    Missed   
3     2018-01-14 00:15:00 2018-01-14 23:45:00     95  Received   
4     2018-01-15 00:00:00 2018-01-15 04:45:00     20    Missed   
5     2018-01-15 05:00:00 2018-01-15 14:00:00     37  Received   
6     2018-01-15 14:15:00 2018-01-15 14:45:00      3    Missed   
7     2018-01-15 15:00:00 2018-01-15 15:45:00      4  Received   
8     2018-01-15 16:00:00 2018-01-16 23:45:00     31    Missed  

        id
group                    
1      ABC123
2      ABC123
3      ABC123
4      ABC123
5      ABC123
6      ABC123
7      ABC123
8      ABC123
```

When I look at the datatype, it indicates that it's a data frame:

```
In [990]: type(result)
Out[990]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

However, when I attempt to insert the data into MySQL, I get the following error:

```
Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'series' cannot be converted to 
a MySQL type
```

Here is the code that I'm using to insert:

```
for a, b in result.iterrows():

    e_point = result['id'][[a]]
    t = result['type'][[a]]
    num = result['count'][[a]]
    first = result['first'][[a]]
    last = result['last'][[a]]

    try:
       cnx_insert = connector.connect(user='abc', password='abc',
                                         host = 'blah',
                                         port = '3306',
                                         database='some_database')
    except:
        cnx_insert = connector.connect(user='abc', password='abc',
                                     host = 'blah',
                                     port = '3306',
                                     database='some_database')

    cursor_insert = cnx_insert.cursor()
    try:
        values = (id, type, count,  first, last)
        insert_query = ("INSERT INTO some_database.some_table"
                             "(id, message_status, read_intervals, first_reading_time,last_reading_time)"
                             "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
        cursor_insert.execute(insert_query, values) 
        cnx_insert.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print str(id)
        print e
    cnx_insert.close()
```

I never had trouble inserting before and I've tried doing a variety of things to address such as turning the data into a list and tuple.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are using connector to save to mysql. But why so complicated? You can easily use

```
df.to_sql(table_name, connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

to save your dataframe.